# interjection: Fool that I am!

Tags: grammar, syntax

How do you analyze the following phrase? What kind of movement or other operation is involved?

> Fool that I am!

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *analyze*, *movement*, and *operation*. The sentence means  roughly "I am that [kind of] fool. The complement *Fool* is preposed for emphasis.

Comment: What does the sentence look like before the preposing takes place?

Comment: As I wrote, roughly "I am that [kind of] fool"; alternatively "[It's true that] I am a fool" The subject S is the pronoun *I*, the verb V is *am*, and the nominative complement C is *fool*. The ordinary order is S-V-C; the preposed order is C-S-V

Comment: Is the pattern available for other nouns? Can I say "Genius that he is"?

Comment: Yes, the preposition for emphasis is a general operation.

Comment: Are you sure? Any evidence?

Comment: What kind of evidence are you after? user105719 couldn't have been more clear.

Comment: Evidence from Google Books, for example

Comment: What is the grammatical role of "that"?